# How do I mock a google datalayer.push callback function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, google-optimize

The snippet below displays my React hook file that runs Google Optimize AB test.

```
export default function useGetABExperimentType(experimentId) {
  const [experimentType, setExperimentType] = useState('0');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window && window.dataLayer) {
      window.dataLayer.push({
        event: 'optimize.activate',
        eventCallback: () => {
          mySideEffectFunction();
        },
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return experimentType;
}
```

I am trying to test that my `mySideEffectFunction()` function does call to increase test coverage.
In Jest, how do I mock the `eventCallback` callback function from `window.dataLayer.push` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    window.dataLayer = {
      push: jest.fn().mockImplementation(config => {
        config.eventCallback();
      }),
    };
```

I managed to mock and call the callback with this.

Answer (score 0):

so in tests we refer to the `window` as `global`. so you could try mocking like this:

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        dataLayer: {
           push: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
                         eventCallback: jest.fn()
                 })
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this but essentially mocking the `dataLayer` object and then mocking the functions inside it and mocking the implementations. then you should be able to test if the mocked function was called or not

Comment: Thanks for that. That manages to mock it but eventCallback does not call.